# OpenCV C++ resize() not found

Tags: xcode, opencv

I installed opencv 2.4.9 for macOS and integrated it with Xcode. However, although it finds most functions, when calling the resize() function, I get the build error 'Use of undeclared identifier resize'.

Can anybody please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't mention how you are calling it, but there are two `resize` functions: a member of `Mat` that changes the number of rows, and `cv::resize()` that interpolates to resize an image.  For the latter you need imgproc.hpp.

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
//...
cv::resize(src, dst, dst.size(), 0, 0, interpolation);
```

Comment: Well, the documentation didn't mention the file I needed to include, neither any resize() example. Thanks.